# How to find the number of identical rows in a column other than the group by group by SQL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

An easy problem to explain with an example:

I have this table:

```
Country     | Name 
------------------------------
US          |  A
US          |  B 
US          |  A 
US          |  A 
FR          |  A 
FR          |  C 
FR          |  C
```

And I want as result:

```
Country     | Name    | Nname
------------------------------
US          | A       | 3 
US          | B       | 1 
FR          | A       | 1 
FR          | C       | 2
```

I use posgres, how can I do?

Comment: `GROUP BY` is the solution!

Comment: With the group by I can group same country but not count the name

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple `GROUP BY` for this:

```
 SELECT country, name, count(*) as nname
 FROM table
 GROUP BY country, name;
```

Answer (score 0):

check the below

```
 SELECT COUNTRY, NAME, COUNT(NAME) as nname
     FROM THIS_TABLE GROUP BY country, name
```